Agent stopped due to iteration limit or time limit
Facing this error - Agent stopped due to iteration limit or time limit.
my code -
from langchain_experimental.agents import create_csv_agent
from langchain_ollama import OllamaLLM
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

# CSV file path
csv_file = "bike_sales_100k.csv"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

# Initialize the Ollama language model
llm = OllamaLLM(
    model="llama3.1",  # or "llama3.2:1b" if you prefer
    callback_manager=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
    temperature=0
)

# Create the CSV agent
agent = create_csv_agent(
    llm,
    csv_file,
    verbose=True,
    # agent_type="zero-shot-react-description",
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    allow_dangerous_code=True,
    max_iterations=10
)
print(agent)

def query_data(query):
    
    try:
        response = agent.invoke(query)
        print("----------------------",response)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        raise  # Let the error propagate for easier debugging


# Example query
query = "Count total bike sales for hybrid bike"
response = query_data(query)
# print("\nAgent Response:")
# print(response)
print(response['output'])

the agent is running, and giving write pandas query but it is not executing the pandas query. please help. encountering this issue with different providers (Ollama, Groq, and OpenAI), indicating the problem might be related to how the agent is handling execution rather than just a single provider.

Can you share what you are seeing the output since verbose=True is there
